# Issue with Android Exoplayer playing encrypted media from sd-card

Tags: android, aes, media, exoplayer

i am working on an application which read encrypted data from SD-Card of device and play using exoplayer, my code is working successfully when i encrypt media and play in such cases it work perfectly but i am facing issue when i restart application(by the time i already have encrypted media file) and directly play media it gives me following exception

> om.example.myapplication E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException:
>   None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor,
>   FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor,
>   Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor,
>   WavExtractor) could read the stream. at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:722)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:645)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

below is my code for playing media

```
    public void playVideo(View view) {
        mEncryptedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/enc_oliver.mp4");
        Log.e("Enc Filename =", mEncryptedFile.getName());
        if (hasFile()) {
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(
                bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
//        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        mSimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new EncryptedFileDataSourceFactory(mCipher,
                mSecretKeySpec, mIvParameterSpec, bandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(inputFile);
            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
                    extractorsFactory, null, null);
            player.prepare(videoSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR!!", "File not found");
        }
    }

 public void playAudio(View view) {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(
                bandwidthMeter);

        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);

        DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new EncryptedFileDataSourceFactory(mCipher,
                mSecretKeySpec, mIvParameterSpec, defaultBandwidthMeter);

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mEncryptedFile);
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
                extractorsFactory, null, null);
        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

i am using following mechanism to encrypt file for the first time which result in success for first time second time onward it won't execute 'cos i already have encrypted file

```
public static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    public static final String AES_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    private void initKey() {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        key = "abctestkeyforand".getBytes();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);

        mSecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES_ALGORITHM);
        mIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);


    }

public void encryptFiles(View view) {
        File musicDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()
                + "/Music");
        File[] audioFiles = musicDirectory.listFiles();
        if (audioFiles != null && audioFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File singleAudioFile : audioFiles) {
                inputFile = singleAudioFile;
                Log.e("Input Filename =", inputFile.getName());
                mEncryptedFile = new File(musicDirectory, "enc_" + inputFile.getName());
                Log.e("Enc Filename =", inputFile.getName());
                if (hasFile()) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                            "encrypted file found, no need to recreate");
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);
                    encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mSecretKeySpec, mIvParameterSpec);
                    new EncryptFileTask(inputFile, mEncryptedFile, encryptionCipher).execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void encryptFile(View view) {
        inputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/oliver.mp4");

        Log.e("Input Filename =", inputFile.getName());
        mEncryptedFile = new File(inputFile.getParent(), "enc_" + inputFile.getName());
        Log.e("Enc Filename =", mEncryptedFile.getName());
        if (hasFile()) {
            Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                    "encrypted file found, no need to recreate");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);
            encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mSecretKeySpec, mIvParameterSpec);
            new EncryptFileTask(inputFile, mEncryptedFile, encryptionCipher).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public class EncryptFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private File inputFile;
    private File mFile;
    private Cipher mCipher;

    public EncryptFileTask(File inputFile, File file, Cipher cipher) {

        this.inputFile = inputFile;
        mFile = file;
        mCipher = cipher;
    }

    private boolean downloadAndEncrypt() throws Exception {
        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream,
                    mCipher);

            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            cipherOutputStream.close();

            float totalTimeInSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000f;
            Log.e("Encryption", "Completed for " + inputFile.getName() + " in " + totalTimeInSeconds
                    + " seconds");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

//    connection.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return downloadAndEncrypt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
        Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Encryption done");
        if (aVoid) {
            inputFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

initKey() will be called from onCreate() of an Activity,Please provide me suggestion/solution to resolve this issue

Comment: Do you save the IV? Otherwise you won't be able to decrypt the data.

Comment: nah, currently i am randomly generating IV

Comment: thanks , it saves my day.

Comment: No probs, just don't reuse the same IV for the same key. So you need to randomize it every time you want to do an encryption (not just once in the "init" state).